# HDD performance testing over LAN

Tags: performance, local-area-network, testing

Do you know some utility that allow me for HDD performance testing over lan.

The issue - I have a shared drive with shared file database. Performance of the database is low and I assume that lan-drive communication time might be the problem. Most programs that I saw are intended for direct drive testing.

Can you recommend something for checking read-write drive time. Better free soft.

Comment: Network is many times slower than the HDD. It is rather pointless to try to determine the HDD performance over network. Perhaps you want to determine the performance of the network itself.

Comment: I know that file copying is quite fast, but database operations are slow. I assumed that the problem is in random reads and writes. What should I look for in the performance of the network itself?

Comment: What kind of database? If its some of those Microsoft Access / Borland crap that need to edit a file, oh yes it is slow.

Comment: It's specific database. But I suppose that it is similar to Microsoft Access / Borland.

Comment: I really want to use SQL, but the soft works only that way. My current ideas to improve performance - update lan to 1000mbit and set-up SSD.

Comment: You should use a DBMS when networking with databases. Those databases with direct access to file are too slow to be used through network share.

Comment: If you have no options you can consider setting up Remote Desktop access so the user can run the application directly in the server. This is the solution I had to implement in a similar case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within windows you have performance tools. This can be run over the lan.  Run the test and look at the disk queue length, this will tell you if the hard drive is the bottle neck.